# Why get I an empty sequence from flow_from_directory tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to load test images for my CNN. I get the path of my test images and if I print then the length of it I see that I got successfully the images. The problem is that if I want to get the images from `test_data_gen` I get an empty sequence. This is the [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5zfy.png) .

Here is my code:

```
  # This command only in Colab.
  %tensorflow_version 2.x
except Exception:
  pass
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get project files
!wget https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/project-data/cats-and-dogs/cats_and_dogs.zip

!unzip cats_and_dogs.zip

PATH = 'cats_and_dogs'

train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
validation_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'validation')
test_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'test')

# Get number of files in each directory. The train and validation directories
# each have the subdirecories "dogs" and "cats".
total_train = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(train_dir)])
total_val = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(validation_dir)])
total_test = len(os.listdir(test_dir))

# Variables for pre-processing and training.
batch_size = 128
epochs = 15
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150

test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
e, subset=None, interpolation="nearest")

test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), 
color_mode='rgb', 
classes=None, 
class_mode='categorical', 
batch_size=128, 
shuffle='False', 
seed=None, 
save_to_dir=None, 
save_prefix='', 
save_format='png', 
follow_links=False, 
subset=None, 
interpolation="nearest")
```

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue?so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your `test_data_gen` you need to set class_mode to `None` from `categorical` to return only the images, since test directory contains only images and not class wise folder structure.
Below is the changed code.

```
test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
e, subset=None, interpolation="nearest")

test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), 
color_mode='rgb', 
classes=None, 
class_mode=None, 
batch_size=128, 
shuffle='False', 
seed=None, 
save_to_dir=None, 
save_prefix='', 
save_format='png', 
follow_links=False, 
subset=None, 
interpolation="nearest")
```